# OpenERP V7 Customization in PO

Tags: python, odoo

I'm new to OpenERP V7 Customization, I need some basic helps.
When Click on "Add an Item" in Purchase order Window how to display the Popup screen (form View) instead of grid view to enter data.

Please find the below screenshots:

Grid View 
[image]

Popup Screen (form View)
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are doing by code then update add this record in `purchase_view.xml`.

```
<record id="purchase_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree" position='replace'>
            <tree string="Purchase Order Lines">
                <field name="product_id"
                    on_change="onchange_product_id(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,0,product_uom,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" />
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="date_planned" />
                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"
                    widget="selection" />
                <field name="account_analytic_id" groups="purchase.group_analytic_accounting"
                    domain="[('type','not in',('view','template'))]" />
                <field name="product_qty"
                    on_change="onchange_product_id(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,product_qty,product_uom,parent.partner_id,parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" />
                <field name="product_uom" groups="product.group_uom"
                    on_change="onchange_product_uom(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,product_qty,product_uom,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)" />
                <field name="price_unit" />
                <field name="taxes_id" widget="many2many_tags"
                    domain="[('parent_id','=',False),('type_tax_use','!=','sale')]" />
                <field name="price_subtotal" />
            </tree>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

or activate the developer mode, Edit form view and find for

```
<tree string="Purchase Order Lines" editable="bottom">
```

and replace it by

```
<tree string="Purchase Order Lines">
```

It will work.